# Class access in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a way in C# (4+) for the instance of `class A` (`instanceOfClassA`) in `class B` to access the variable x (as in `SomeMethodInClassA`) without x being public (see code example below)?

```
    class A
    {
    B linkToClassB;

    void SomeMethodInClassA()
    {
    linkToClassB.x = 1;
    }
    };

    class B
    {
    public int x; // This should be accessible from class A without being public

    A instanceOfClassA;
    ...
    };
```

I was wondering that because as `instanceOfClassA` is a member of of `class B` there might be a way to allow a class to access pecific methods of their member classes.

Comment: [MSDN Internal Key word and explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options for `A` being able to access `x` without the classes being part of the same hierarchy:

#### Nested class

If `A` is a nested class inside `B` then `A` can access `x`:

```
class B {
    private int X;
    A instanceOfClassA;

    private class A {
        B linkToClassB;
        void SomeMethodInClassA() { linkToClassB.x = 1; }
    }
}
```

#### `internal` access

If the two classes are in the same assembly and `x` is be `internal` then it is possible for `A` to access it. Of course in this case it is possible to access `x` from all other classes in the same assembly as well, which might not be desirable.

```
class A
{
    B linkToClassB;

    void SomeMethodInClassA() { linkToClassB.x = 1; }
}

class B
{
    internal int x;
    A instanceOfClassA;
}
```

Comment: Great, the nested class solution was exactly the functionality that I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `x` as

```
internal int x;
```

and as long as `A` and `B` are in the same assembly it will work. `internal` is provided precisely for this kind of situation and in C# it's the only mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you were allowed to access private members of other class,the very purpose of `Encapsulation` in `OOP` would be destroyed..

You cant access `private` members of other class unless you use `Property`(which needs to be public) or `Reflection`

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the property using an explicit implementation of an interface. That way the property is reachable using a reference to the interface, but it's not reachable using a reference to the class:

```
public class A {

  private AccessB linkToB;

  void SomeMethodInClassA() {
    linkToB.X = 1;
  }

}

public interface AccessB {

  int X { get; set; }

}

public class B : AccessB {

  private int x;

  int AccessB.X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `internal` keyword will do what you want. It only allows access from within the **same  assembly** (think *DLL* or *EXE*).

More importantly however, you should think of *why* you want this type of functionality. It is best practice to **avoid coupling** (two classes relying on each other). Can something be passed in the *constructor* of object *A* or *B* that would allow them to share data? Perhaps a `public` property with a `set` accessor on either *A* or *B*?

There are cases where `internal` is the best choice, but just as a screwdriver can be used to hammer nails, it doesn't make it the best approach for everything. I would advise you use `internal` as a last resort if every other option just is not viable.

To give you an idea of what the `internal` keyword is great for, let's consider platform invoking (*pInvoke*) Win32 functions from within *C#*:

```
[Flags]
internal enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
  None = 0x0,
  VmOperation = 0x8,
  VmRead = 0x10,
  VmWrite = 0x20,
  QueryInformation = 0x400
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  internal static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags desiredAccess,
                                            bool inheritHandle,
                                            int processId);
  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  internal static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, 
                                                IntPtr baseAddress,
                                                byte[] buffer,
                                                int count, 
                                                out int numberOfBytesRead);

  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  internal static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, 
                                                 IntPtr baseAddress,
                                                 byte[] buffer,
                                                 int count, 
                                                 out int numberOfBytesWritten);

  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  internal static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

  [DllImport("kernel32")]
  internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
}
```

Here the `internal` keyword makes a lot of sense because various classes in my library may need access to `NativeMethods.CloseHandle()` or the like. However, I don't want people who may use my class library to have access to the `NativeMethods` class since it is strictly for under-the-hood implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it `internal`, so only classes in that assembly/DLL can access it, including A.
But there may be a better pattern, depending what you want to do with it.